# how to fix opacity on IE6

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, internet-explorer-6

how to fix opacity on IE6

This code does not work on IE6 !

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
```

And this code !

```
$('#description').animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);
```

Comment: IE 6 is depreciated , even google have stopd supporting it , you should too.

Comment: @Aviatrix - do you have a link that point to `even google have stopd supporting it` ?

Comment: @Aviatrix Technically, only YouTube, which surely doesn't include the whole of Google

Comment: @reigel , here you go http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/01/modern-browsers-for-modern-applications.html
@faressoft , show those users that they are using outdated browser and that they might not see the site properly due to that. and provide links to other borwsers , opera , chrome , ff ..

Comment: @Aviatrix - wishing google was my only client ;)

Comment: @faresoft - I agree that when you have a lot of users on IE6 you do need to support it. However that doesn't mean you have to make it perfect for them. Opacity may be difficult to get right in IE6, but if the site works without it, then perhaps they can live without it; IE6 users won't quite such a nice site, but they'll still be able to use it. (It might even encourage them to upgrade!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working with `opacity` in jQuery, then the [`fadeIn`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), [`faceOut`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [`fadeTo`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) function should be better than `animate`. In your case it would be

```
$('#description').fadeOut(1000);
```

Or with `fadeTo`,

```
$('#description').fadeOut(1000, 0.0);
```

---

But it is work on IE6! :(

http://jsbin.com/owisa/3

Where it is not work?

Comment: @faressoft - I think this one is working. Which part did it not work on you?

Answer (score 1):

Your styled element needs to [have layout](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html) for the filter to render properly.

Try:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
display: inline-block;
```

Or:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=50);
-moz-opacity:0.5;
-khtml-opacity: 0.5;
opacity: 0.5;
zoom: 1;
```