# Opacity doesn't work on IE6

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opacity Properity in IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8888792/opacity-properity-in-ie6)

Following code is not working in IE6:

```
overlayCSS: {background: 'black', opacity: .8}
```

How can it be solved?

Comment: Did you try filter:alpha(opacity=80). This works in IE6 I think.

Comment: The problem is background: 'black' :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  filter:alpha(opacity=80);
  opacity: 0.8;
```

It should be work in IE.

Answer (score 3):

IE6 is "special". the opacity is filter alpha for IE5.5+

[how to fix opacity on IE6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749328/how-to-fix-opacity-on-ie6)

http://css-tricks.com/css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve opacity in IE6 with jQuery is to use the `.fadeTo()` function:

```
$('#myelem').fadeTo('0.8');
```

Or in CSS, I think IE6 supports the non-standard `filter`:

```
filter:alpha(opacity=80);
```

For this to work though, the element must have layout - if it doesn't, there is a bit of hack that will force the element to have layout:

```
zoom: 1;
```